# Oracle LAG on groups of related rows

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Given this data:

```
LINE DATE
1   08/19/2016
2   08/19/2016
3   08/19/2016
1   07/29/2016
2   07/29/2016
1   06/24/2012
2   06/24/2012
3   06/24/2012
```

I'd like to generate:

```
LINE DATE PRIOR_DATE
1   08/19/2016  07/29/2016
2   08/19/2016  07/29/2016
3   08/19/2016  07/29/2016
1   07/29/2016  06/24/2016
2   07/29/2016  06/24/2016
1   06/24/2012  <NULL>
2   06/24/2012  <NULL>
3   06/24/2012  <NULL>
```

This query:

```
SELECT line, date,LAG(date, 1) OVER (partition by date ORDER BY date) AS prior_date ...
```

Generates:

```
1   08/19/2016  
2   08/19/2016  08/19/2016
3   08/19/2016  08/19/2016
1   07/29/2016  
2   07/29/2016  07/29/2016
1   06/24/2012  
2   06/24/2012  06/24/2012
3   06/24/2012  06/24/2012
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You probably need another field to indicate the order, remember db set arent order.

Comment: Also you need to explain the logic, At first looks like `partition by LINE` should solve it, but not sure how you get this `3   08/19/2016  07/29/2016` in your result, line 3 doesnt have `07/29/2016`

Comment: Why are you expecting 07/29/2016 for the line = 3 and date = 08/19/2016 row? Surely the previous date for that line is 06/24/2012? My initial thought is you're after `LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY line ORDER BY dt)` (using "dt" instead of "date" for the column name since "date" is a reserved word) but that doesn't match to the results you're after either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the result you're actually after, it could be LAST_VALUE() you need or LAG().

I've given both here, so you can see the differences:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 line, to_date('08/19/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 line, to_date('08/19/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 line, to_date('08/19/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 line, to_date('07/29/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 line, to_date('07/29/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 line, to_date('06/24/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 line, to_date('06/24/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 line, to_date('06/24/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking a table with data in it
SELECT line,
       dt,
       last_value(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) prior_dt1,
       LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY line ORDER BY dt) prior_dt2
FROM   sample_data
ORDER BY dt DESC, line;

      LINE DT          PRIOR_DT1   PRIOR_DT2
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
         1 19/08/2016  29/07/2016  29/07/2016
         2 19/08/2016  29/07/2016  29/07/2016
         3 19/08/2016  29/07/2016  24/06/2012
         1 29/07/2016  24/06/2012  24/06/2012
         2 29/07/2016  24/06/2012  24/06/2012
         1 24/06/2012              
         2 24/06/2012              
         3 24/06/2012
```

Comment: `last_value` was what I needed.